# What is an aurora called when viewed from space?

Tags: auroras

An aurora is defined as a electromagnetic instance caused by polarization and ionization within a planet's higher altitudes. But what are the different phasics (beginning, middle and end) and perspectives (planetside/spaceside) of an aurora if observed from a 3 dimensional view.

The question: What is an aurora called when viewed from space?

Comment: An aurora, no?  Certainly I've seen multiple articles using the word for the phenomenon both on Earth and other planets.  Most recently Uranus: http://www.zmescience.com/space/aurora-on-neptune/

Answer (score 2):

It is still referred to as an 'aurora', examples include a relatively recent report from NASA - [Stunning Aurora from Space](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/goddard/2016/stunning-aurora-from-space).  Further, the aptly named document from NASA - [Aurora](https://pwg.gsfc.nasa.gov/polar/EPO/auroral_poster/aurora_all.pdf) - refers to the phenomenon by that name in reference to when it is observed from the surface or from space.

Whether viewed from the surface or from space, the phenomenon is still called an aurora.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki It looks like this user immediately deleted their account after answering the question.

Comment: @gerrit I ask the reason of that, though.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I don't know why this user deleted their account, and I can't think of any reasonable way to find out.